# Append 2 webservices data in one uiPickerView component

Tags: ios, web-services, uipickerview

Here is my Problem, I am sorry if it is a very frequent question.

I had a web-service from which I was getting projects and Holidays from different methods. Now I just want this Holidays and projects to be loaded into the `uipickerview` in a single component.

For example I had my projects with names `proj1, proj2,proj3` which is coming from `getProjects` method from web-service.

Similarly I had holidays with names `sickleave, casual leave` which is coming from `getHolidays` method from web-service.

So I want in such a way that `sickleave,casual leave,proj1,proj2` to be displayed in a single component in a `uipickerview`

I guess somehow some answers were stating to use NSMutableArray, But I dont know how to use that...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow these steps:

1. Declare and initialize an NSMutableArray.
2. Use addObject method on your NSMutableArray to add objects in your array from both WebServices. You will be required to loop through till the WebServices are returning values.
3. Outside of your loop use: `[picker reloadAllComponents]`
4. Use picker view delegate methods as:

   ```
   - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
   {        
   return [yourArray count];
   }
   - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
   {
   return  1 ;
   }
   - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
           forComponent:(NSInteger)component
   {
   return [yourArray objectAtIndex:row];
   }
   ```

Also don't forget to connect your picker view delegate and datasource.